# Why is this function homogenous to the specified degree?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, special-functions

I have this function

$$ w(q) = (1 - \alpha)q^nBk^\alpha + c $$

The paper I'm reading says that w is homogenous of degree

$$ n/(1-\alpha) $$

and so small differences in q cause large differences in w. Why is it 'homogenous' to this degree and why does that cause large differences in q to occur with small change in w?

Comment: I suspect a transcription error. As written the function is not homogeneous if $c$ is some nonzero constant. If $c=0$, $w(q)$ is homogeneous of degree $n$ since $w(\alpha q) = \alpha^n w(q)$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) for example.

Comment: You write, "small differences in $q$ cause large differences in $w$," then you ask why small changes in $w$ cause large differences in $q$. You might want to edit your question for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $\alpha,n,B,k,c$ are all constant, then for small $\epsilon$ we have $$w(q+\epsilon)\approx w(q)+\epsilon w'(q)=w(q)+\epsilon n(1-\alpha)q^{n-1}Bk^{\alpha}$$ So if $n$ is large then that small change in $q$ has made a big change in $w$.